# Entity Framework 5, Multiple Models, Same Entity

Tags: entity-framework

Ok, so I am new to entity framework...

I have an existing SQL database with some 500 tables in it, and we are in the process of considering a move from Linq->SQL to Entity Framework as our main data access layer. We also want to consider more of a domain driven design approach with separate data contexts managing key areas of the application ( i.e. Sales, Marketing, Jobs, Shipping etc. etc. ).

If we take a common entity such as "Customer", this appears in more than one model. I have two models in my sample app so far. Entity Framework is clever enough to create only one customer class ( we are using the default Poco T4 templates for class generation ), however when I try and run the project I get the following error "Multiple types with the name 'Customer' exist in the EdmItemCollection in different namespaces.  Convention based mapping requires unique names without regard to namespace in the EdmItemCollection".

So am I right in thinking that Entity Framework does not allow "Customer" to exist in more than one model ? If I really want customer appearing in more than one model, do I have to start creating different versions of the customer class to deal with it ?

Apologies in advance if this is a dumb question, but I am relatively new to EF.

Thanks...

Comment: You can certainly have two same models however, they should not overlap. If they overlap then , EF will not be able to find which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you are creating DDD with bounded context. In bounded context, you create more than one context with one or more related entities in it. Why do you want to create more than one model with the same name?

Check the Julie Lerman's link for reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

Sorry if I am out of context. But, in my experience in such a scenario, we have to create two different context such as "MarketingModelContext" and SalesModelContext. MarketingModelContext will have all the dbsets related to marketingmodel along with customer entity. In the same way, SalesModelContext will have all the dbsets related to SalesModel along with customer entity. In this way, you will be creating only one customer entity or POCO which can be used by two contexts independently. This is known as bounded contexts as Julie Lerman calls it. It will help you in separation of context, concerns and helps you with better performance as only required context(fewer entities) can be loaded. The above article will help you with this.

Hope I have answered your query.

Comment: So here is where I am at. I have one project with two models present. One containing tables which relate to my marketing activity and one to sales. The models have different names i.e. "MarketingModel" and "SalesModel", but the entity Customer is common to both. I assume therefore that it's logical to have each model contain the entities that relate to the particular part of the system in question. Am I making sense ?

Comment: Bibek, I agree with everything in your comment. I have two models, both of which contain the customer entity. This is actually where I started my original question. Entity framework still does not like having the Customer entity in more than one model. Sorry if I am missing the point.